# How to use more than one database in ASP.NET MVC4 project (EF)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I want to use different SQL Server 2012 databases into an ASP.NET MVC4 project. Some databases already designed and filled by data, one database will be designed during site development. Every databases has `Id` columns that links to entities from others databases (without foreign keys).

I know how to link this databases into NHibernate, but I want to do this project under ADO.NET Entity Framework.

1. Can I link 3-5 SQL Server databases located on one server?
2. How to define connection string(s) for this databases?
3. How to specify tables->db's relationship by code?

Comment: You basically need one distinct EDMX model (if you go the model-based approach of Entity Framework) or one `DbContext` descendants (if you want to use code-first approach) for each distinct database - EF doesn't support *cross-database* models.

Comment: So I can use 4 EDMX models and 1 DBContext together in one project but without linking it? Maybe I can use LinkedServers technique?

Comment: You would have **4 EDMX models** and also **4 DbContext** classes.